# NumberFormatException message doesnt change?

Tags: java

In the following code, how can I change the message that keeps displaying ("C++");
according to the element of the array? and why does that happened? why the message doesn't change?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Testslsl {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String languages[] = {"C", "C++", "Java", "Perl","Python" };

        int num;

        for (int c = 0; c <= 5; c++) {
            try {
                System.out.println(languages[c]);

                if (languages[c].charAt(2)=='+')
                    System.out.println("it is C plus plus");

                num = Integer.parseInt(languages[1]);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                input.next();
            }
            catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
            catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException exp) {
                System.out.println(exp);
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

Output:

```
C
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2
C++
it is C plus plus
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "C++"
Java
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "C++"
Perl
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "C++"
Python
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "C++"
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
```

Comment: `languages[1]` is `"C++"`, that's not an `int` so it isn't clear what value you expect in `num`.

Comment: I know but why does the message (C++ ) of the exception keeps displaying although the element changes !

Comment: One is `languages[c]` the other is `languages[1]`, do you see the difference?

Comment: Woow ! I didn't notice that At ALL ! LOL Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

The message is the same because you're always attaining `languages[1]`, which is always the string `C++`.

In order to iterate over the other elements of your array, you'll need to use your index `c`:

```
num = Integer.parseInt(languages[c]);
```

Nevertheless, as mentioned in the comments, since you have a String array, it isn't quite clear why you're using the `Integer.parseInt` in order to attain an `int`. It will always result in a `NumberFormatException`.

Instead, you should have:

```
String language = languages[c];
```

Comment: It it a tutorial trace question (Homework) so,I can't change the code ,can I ?>_<

Comment: @user6162628, Oh ok... That point wasn't mentioned in the question though. :)